# highchart intra day with ajax json php data

Tags: php, jquery, json, highcharts

I've been trying to create a highchart intra-day chart with ajax json php data but no luck. please take a look at my code.

chart.php:

```
//Filename: chart.php
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    $.getJSON('http://yourdomain.com/json.php', function(data) {

        // create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {


            title: {
                text: 'AAPL stock price by minute'
            },

            xAxis: {
                gapGridLineWidth: 0
            },

            rangeSelector : {
                buttons : [{
                    type : 'hour',
                    count : 1,
                    text : '1h'
                }, {
                    type : 'day',
                    count : 1,
                    text : '1D'
                }

                /*, {
                    type : 'all',
                    count : 1,
                    text : 'All'
                }*/

                ],
                selected : 1,
                inputEnabled : false
            },

            series : [{
                name : 'AAPL',
                type: 'area',
                data : data,
                gapSize: 5,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                },
                fillColor : {
                    linearGradient : {
                        x1: 0, 
                        y1: 0, 
                        x2: 0, 
                        y2: 1
                    },
                    stops : [
                        [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]], 
                        [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                    ]
                },
                threshold: null
            }]
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

json.php:

```
//Filename: json.php
$arr = array( array(1405578572,2.3,373.25,372.3,2.15),
          array(1405589777,3.3,373.25,372.3,3.15),
          array(1405649399,4.3,373.25,372.3,4.15),
          array(1405649843,5.3,373.25,372.3,5.15),
          array(1405649896,2.3,373.25,372.3,2.15)
);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

I have tried everything I could but I couldnt get the highchart intra-day chart work with json data.

Please help me with a sample of highchart intra day chart sample with PHP.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/intraday-area/

Comment: Make sure that data is in correct format. Create temporary variable and assign data as per demo format and check it's working or not. This way we can check data is in correct format or not.

Comment: Do you receive any errors in the console? Probably you have one of two problems, first incorrect json, second problem with different domain. I mean that your json is not on the same domain as your highcharts applciation / web.